# Proof of the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}{(1+\frac xn)^n} \; = e^x $ for any $x$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So I have been trying to prove this formula for the limit of a sequence of the form $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}{(1+\frac xn)^n} \; = e^x $$ for any $x$

I started by taking the natural log of $a_n$ to simplify the form to $$ n\ln (1+ \frac xn) = \frac {\ln(1+\frac xn)}{\frac 1n} $$

Now if you take the $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, we get the indeterminate form $\frac 00$

So then by L'Hopital's rule, it becomes $$\frac 1{n^4 + xn^3} $$ and here I feel like I hit a dead end because we still can't get a limit.

Does anybody see a mistake I made? I am looking for some clues. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you used L'Hospital's rule, you did something wrong, for: Let $f(n) = \log(1+\frac xn)$ denote the numerator and $g(n) = \frac 1n$ the denominator, then 
$$ f'(n) = \frac 1{1 + \frac xn}\cdot \left(-\frac x{n^2}\right) = -\frac{x}{n^2+nx},\quad g'(n) = -\frac 1{n^2} $$
Hence 
$$ \frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)} = \frac{n^2x}{n^2+nx} = \frac{x}{1 + \frac xn} \to x $$