# Proof of $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1 + \frac{b}{n})^n = e^b$

Tags: limits, constants, indeterminate-forms

I found one definition of $e$ to be  $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n = e$ and I checked it with a graphing calculator to be true. However the $1$ in the numerator is a special case, where it can be replaced with a different number and it affects the power to which $e$ is raised.
I could not find anyone prove this specifically, I found [one proving the $b = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/550728) case (1233dfv's answer), which I thought I could use to prove the $b = b$ case.
My go at it:

$y  =  \lim_{n\to \infty}(1 + \frac{b}{n})^n$
$\ln(y)  = \lim_{n\to \infty}n\ln(1 + \frac{b}{n})$ (indeterminate form "$\infty\times  0$") 
$\ln(y)  =  \lim_{n\to \infty} \ln(1+\frac{b}{n})/(\frac{1}{n})$ (indeterminate form "$0 / 0$", can use L'Hopital rule) 
$\ln(y)  =  \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{1+\frac{b}{n}}\cdot\frac{-b}{n^2}}{\frac{-1}{n^2}}$ 
$\ln(y) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{b}{n}} \cdot b$

Since $b$ is a number and infinity is not, $b/n = 0$, thus

$\ln(y) = b$
$\ln(y) = \ln(e^b)$
$y = e^b$

Are my calculations and reasoning correct?

Comment: I assume $n\in\mathbb N$. How do you apply L'Hopital in discrete case? (You can but it requires a bit of explaining).

Comment: Alternatively think about the following $$ \lim _{n\to\infty} \left ( 1+\frac{b}{n} \right) ^n = \lim _{n\to\infty} \left[\left ( 1+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{n}{b}\right)} \right) ^{n/b}\right] ^b $$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/358830 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/989676 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/849173 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3391196

Comment: @AlvinL Wow, that is elegant! But this is the first time I see used that n can be replaced with f(n) if f(n) -> inf when n -> infinity. It seems to make sense, but seems also exotic, I don't see it in this list of limit properties: ( https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitsProperties.aspx ). Could you provide some proof or another example of this property being used?